# Running Grails and Sencha ExtJS in one Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, extjs, intellij-idea, extjs6

Have an application that is run with the frontend made in ExtJS while the backend is built using Grails.

The ExtJS application is built and deployed from the Windows command line using `sencha app build` then `sencha web start` which starts the application on port 80. All good. Next, the Grails application is run through IntelliJ (`Run->Run 'Application'`) but that runs in port 8080.

How is it possible to call the services in Grails from the ExtJS application since it depends on being under the same port? Is there a way to deploy the applications under one Tomcat instance through a vhost?

Comment: Are you asking just for development environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your ExtJS to make calls to other ports by enabling CORS on both server and client side.

**Grails**

To enable CORS on grails side you can install this [plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/cors) and add the following config to your Config.groovy. Basically we are telling that any domain can make requests to this application.

```
cors {
    enabled = true
    url.pattern = '*'
    allow.origin.regex = '.*'
    headers=[
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, authorization, accept, cookie, set-cookie, content-type, x-requested-with',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': 3600
    ]
}
```

**ExtJS**

We need to enable the CORS on ExtJS side as well, to do this we can simply add a `beforerequest` listener for all AJAX requests. Also i prefer to have a common place where i can configure my API Url, so instead of defining the API URL in all places like proxies, ajax requests we can centralize this.

You can do that by adding the following code in your application launch method.

```
var API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/grailsappp'
Ext.Ajax.on({
     beforerequest: function(conn, opts){        
        if(opts.url) {
            opts.url = API_URL + opts.url;
        }
        conn.setCors(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got part way through with this. Now the backend service calls through ExtJS. Only issue is the CORS part is still a bit confusing. I've added it on the Grails side (I'm using v3.0.2) as mentioned, however the requests are still being sent as OPTIONS instead of POST from ExtJS.

Comment: Yeah with CORS enabled, it will send two requests. One is the preflight request  (OPTIONS) and the other one is the actual request (POST).

Answer (score 0):

The Sencha Web Start command is useless if you have a backend that isn't node.js.

For web servers, ExtJS is nothing but static files, because it is served to and interpreted by the browser. I don't know about tomcat/grails specifically, but every web server should be able to serve static files somehow.

I use ASP.NET backend, for example, and I have the ExtJS files added to the ASP.NET project working directory. So when I want to debug, I start the backend debug process locally from VisualStudio, and I can load the static javascript files, which then can access the backend process. I never used `Sencha Web Start`, because as I said, if you have a backend that isn't node.js, it is useless.

You would have to do the same for tomcat/grails. How to achieve this is a pure tomcat/grails question that has nothing to do with ExtJS.

Comment: NodeJS isn't an option for us unfortunately since the project was started with using the Grails framework for the backend. On our local machines to debug is where we are having issues. 

The ExtJS application connects to the Grails app backend, however the calls to the Grails app from ExtJS is from the default ExtJS port, not the port the Grails application is running on.

Comment: I expanded my answer a bit.